# Particles in a box simulation of vacuum system; how to treat scattering from walls?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, vacuum, molecular-dynamics

**note:** I expect that a microscopic treatment of the rate of heat transfer between gases and solid surfaces will likely need to address this as well and so I'm looking in to that today, but if someone beats me to it that would be great!

For example Singh et al. (2009) J. App. Phys. 106, 024314 [Modeling of subcontinuum thermal transport across semiconductor-gasinterfaces](https://docs.lib.purdue.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1022&context=prism) seems to address this using a Boltzman distribution for the gas atoms in the vauum and for *phonons* rather than individual atoms of the solid. However I can’t see how to apply that microscopically on a per-collision basis without estimating how many phonons are involved; is it one phonon on average? More? Less?

Figures at the end of [The Interaction of Molecular Beams with Solid Surfaces](https://www.osti.gov/servlets/purl/4419031) show that the spread in angles of atoms incident at 45 degrees does get wider with increased surface temperature, but there is no information on changes in kinetic energy, but Wikipedia's [Helium atom scattering; Inelastic measurements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helium_atom_scattering#Inelastic_measurements) suggests that interactions with phonons can lead to a much more complicated picture.

---

I'm writing a simple Monte-Carlo simulation for an ultra-high vacuum chamber. I'll initially distribute atoms randomly in position and direction and with speeds derived from a [Maxwell-Boltzmann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%E2%80%93Boltzmann_distribution) distribution. At one end there is a tube of variable length; once a particle passes the far end of it it will be considered "pumped" and no longer tracked.

The idea is to address the effect of a long narrow tube between the chamber and the pump on the effective pumping speed.

I'll assume a monatomic gas with no internal degrees of freedom.

I can introduce the effect of wall roughness by randomly varying the microscopic surface normal from the macroscopic normal at each collision, but I can't think of a way to handle the random momentum transfer effects due to thermal vibrations of the atoms in the wall. These can both change the kinetic energy and the direction of scattering.

What would be a simple, first principles way to introduce it?

I can imagine treating the atom in the wall as a free particle with a similar thermal distribution of speed and direction, but the atoms of the wall are not free, they're constrained by bonds to adjacent atoms.

Perhaps

Comment: There's a silent drive-by close vote for "needs more focus" but I think the problem is very clear and focused; an atom collides with a wall, what would be a simple first principles way to address the momentum transfer due to thermal motion of *bound atoms* in the wall?

Comment: Depends on the wall, right? If it's an ideally insulating wall, then microscopically that corresponds to the atom just bouncing off without any further effect. If it's an ideally conducting wall, you should just draw the atom's final speed from the Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution of temperature $T$, where $T$ is the wall temperature.

Comment: @knzhou only the top layer of atoms of the wall interact with the atoms of gas, so for individual collisions with real walls and UHV gas densities I don't think it matters if the walls are made of ceramic or metal. What you've described doesn't take into account the incoming energy of the gas atom and instead simply resets it based on the wall temperature. I suppose after several collisions that's fine, but I don't see how to include the effect of the thermal motion of wall atoms on the *direction* of scatter. Are you proposing to completely randomize scatter direction isotropically each time?

Comment: Right, that's what I meant by "ideally conducting", i.e. the effect of one collision is like what happens after many collisions with a nonideal wall. This should completely randomize direction as well.

Comment: If you want something in between ideally insulating and ideally conducting, I feel like it's going to depend on the details of how you model the atoms in the wall, so that there's no canonical answer...

Comment: @knzhou I haven't asked for a *canonical answer*, I've asked for a reasonable starting point. The two extremes you've mentioned have no examples in the real world; there are no physical surfaces *so insulating* nor *so conducting* that they behave in the way's you've described.

Comment: Then how about doing it randomly? Do the "ideally insulating" thing, say, 99% of the time, and the "ideally conducting" thing the rest of the time. You can tune the probability as you want.

Comment: @knzhou I've added a bit more and a citation at the beginning. Perhaps phonon exchange is the way to go, but I don't yet know how.

Comment: Unless the effective temperature of the gas is way different than the wall temperature I'm not sure how much difference it all makes. The pumping effectiveness comes down to how many possible paths lead to the exit, and the details of the interactions with the wall really don't matter (since those details impact calculation of all the paths) unless they are directed in some non-random way (such as a turbo pump for example!).

Comment: @JonCuster when writing a simulation one should not say to one's self "I'm not sure how important this bit of physics is so I'm not going to worry about it". The simulation is only background; describing what brought me to this question. My actual question is about the physics of atoms at thermal velocities incident on surfaces and how they scatter, which is interesting by itself. Helium scattering has been used as a probe of phonons in the past at least, I'm trying to read up on that now...

Comment: Fair enough, but one also doesn’t try to incorporate all conceivable physics without a good reason. So, my first pass might be to consider the dispersion curve for phonons in some nice material and see how that would impact He atoms.

Comment: Since it is too late to migrate, I've [asked this separately](https://materials.stackexchange.com/q/528/201) in Materials Modeling SE.

Comment: Perhaps look to what MolFlow does.

Comment: @JonCuster It looks like they just give some simplistic parameters and leave it up to you! https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqbKg.png  from [here](https://molflow.web.cern.ch/sites/molflow.web.cern.ch/files/molflow_user_guide.pdf) It would be great to have an actual physics-based understanding of the atomic scattering process, but in the mean time I can just follow what they do to get something going. *Thanks!*